# how do you detect if a job completes correctly with register-object event

Tags: powershell, jobs

I currently am sending off a job to be processed in the background, and im wondering if i give the client the option to cancel the background job, how do i get the state of the job in the background. for example down here I am using a register-object event state change to not slow down the software while its running, but i want to be able to tell if the job completed or was stopped. so I can send back an appropriate message to the user. I have been playing with this for a few days and haven't been able to wrap my mind around what to do.

```
$script:job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($HostName, $username)
$Destination = "C:\Support\$($username)-$($hostname)-$(get-date -f "MM-dd-yyyy").zip"
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Report completed.", "Report")
} -ArgumentList ($HostName, $username)

$pso = new-object psobject -property @{job = $script:job.Id; JobState = $script:job.State} #statechanged
$jobEvent = Register-ObjectEvent $job Statechanged -MessageData $pso -Action {
   if($event.messagedata.JobState -eq 'Complete')
     {
       [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Report completed.", "Report")
     }
   else
     {
       [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Report was canceled.", "Report")
     }
  }
```

Edit:

Comment: "a job to be processed in the background" - what kind of job? Please show us how/what you assigned to `$script:job`

Comment: apologies
 ```$script:job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($HostName, $username)
$Destination = "C:\Support\$($username)-$($hostname)-$(get-date -f "MM-dd-yyyy").zip"
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Report completed.", "Report")
} -ArgumentList ($HostName, $username)```

updated above as well.